# How to get the packagename of fields by reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I'd like to detect fields in my class that either are custom fields (like `Address` or are native java fields.

Therefore I'm trying to read the package name of each field (to later check if they start with `java.*`.

```
public class ReflectionTest {
    public class MyDTO {
        private String name;
        private Address address;
    }

    public class Address {
        private String street;
        private String zip;
        private String town;
    }


    @Test
    public void testPackageName() {
        for (Field field : MyDTO.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            //always: java.lang.Class
            System.out.println(field.getGenericType().getClass().getPackage().getName()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: the package shown is always `java.lang`. Why?

Comment: well, you are asking it for `MyDTO.class`, so it returns a class object, which is in `java.lang`.

Comment: You query the generic type: `field.getGenericType()...`. I think what you actually want is `field.getType()...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `getType()` instead of `getGenericType()`. Consider this example:

```
public class Sandbox {

    public int intField;
    public Sandbox myField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.stream(Sandbox.class.getDeclaredFields()).forEach(f ->
                System.out.println(f.getName() + " : " + f.getType().getName()));

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
intField : int
myField : my.answer.Sandbox
```

Comment: Would you favor `getName()` or `getCanonialName()`?

Comment: Unfortunately for a `private boolean boolfield;` this does not print out `java.lang.boolean`, but just 'boolean`. So this won't work detecting custom objects.

Comment: @membersound Canonical names *would* be better here (see [example](http://ideone.com/ioUxvP)), but the whole name approach is just really not great, some reasons for which you've already pointed out.

Comment: What is the criterion of a custom type? `Field.getPackage()` is null for primitive types. We have to define the filter criterion first.

Comment: Ok then I could exclude any fields whose package is null, and check the others for the package name.

Comment: It would be cleaner to use `f.getType().isPrimitive()` to handle primitive types. That’s better than using a heuristic like a `null` package. If you want to identify “custom” classes, `f.getType().getClassLoader()` provides better hints. A `null` class loader indicates classes loaded by the bootstrap loader, i.e. system classes, regardless of whether their package is `java. …`, `javax. …`, `org.w3c. …`, `org.omg. …`, `sun. …`, `com.sun. …`, or `com.oracle. …`.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang` is a package that is imported implicitly on any Java class. That's why you can reference many classes contained in it (Like Object, or String), without including any import in your source.

However, nothing prevents you or anyone from creating a package named `java.lang` and including your own classes in it. So this is not a practical way to distinguish native Java (whatever you think this is) from custom fields.

I think you should also find out the classloader that loaded each particular class  you're testing.

Comment: “nothing prevents you or anyone from creating a package named `java.lang`”—except formal rules like that class loaders will reject any attempt to load a class whose name starts with `java.` from the user class path.